# Generating the dual of a non-crossing partition

Tags: python, set, combinatorics

Consider the set of numbers S = [1, 2, ..., n]. A partition divides S into blocks. These blocks are non-crossing if there do not exist elements a < b < c < d with a and c in the same block, but b and d in the same but different block.

Python code for generating the list of non-crossing partitions was given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75576129/19383220) answer.

I am trying to write a function that given a non-crossing partition, returns its dual or Kreweras complement.

The definition of Kreweras complement can be found in [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/301898255_Noncommutative_free_cumulants).

Definition of Kreweras complement
[image: Definition of Kreweras complement]

A nice visualization is given in this other paper. Where the primal non-crossing partition is denoted with the A nodes and the dual with the B nodes.

Non-crossing partition and its dual
[image: Non-crossing partition and its dual]

Below is my attempt. The idea is that the primal partition is ordered, and you can process it in order. If the current primal node say (A1) is isolated, then you can connect the corresponding dual with the next node (e.g. B1 with B2). When you arrive at the last node, you can check whether you can connect the last dual node with the block of the first node; if so, you can merge the first block and the last.

This seems to work well but is missing some edge cases.

For example, if the primal non-crossing partition is [[1,2], [3], [4,5]]. The algorithm should return [[1], [2,3,5], [ 4]]

```
def find_integer_in_list_of_lists(list_of_lists, target_integer):
    # Iterating through each sublist
    for index, sublist in enumerate(list_of_lists):
        # If the target integer is in the sublist
        if target_integer in sublist:
            # Return the index of the sublist and its length
            return index, len(sublist)
    # If the integer is not found in any sublist
    return -1, -1

def is_isolated(list_of_lists, target_integer):
    block_index, block_len = find_integer_in_list_of_lists(list_of_lists, target_integer)
    if(block_len == 1):
        return True
    else:
        return False
    
def append_last_to_first(list_of_lists):
    # If the list of lists is empty or contains only one sublist, return it as is
    if len(list_of_lists) < 2:
        return list_of_lists

    # Append the last sublist to the first sublist
    list_of_lists[0] += list_of_lists[-1]
    
    # Remove the last sublist from the list of lists
    new_list_of_lists = list_of_lists[:-1]

    return new_list_of_lists

def construct_dual_partition(primal_partition, n):

    dual_partition = [[1]]
    current_block = 0
    
    for node in range(1, n):
        if(is_isolated(primal_partition, node)):
            dual_partition[current_block].append(node+1)
        else:
            dual_partition.append([node+1])
            current_block = current_block + 1
    
    if(is_isolated(primal_partition, 1)):
        dual_partition = append_last_to_first(dual_partition)
    
    return dual_partition
```